# Flutter best way to get size/position of widget when it doesn't render

Tags: dart, flutter

I know, How to get size/position of the widget. But question is If we want to get size/position of widget that will be shown after success of `FutureBuilder` then how can we get?

For more clear:

I have below hierarchy of the widget.

> - CustomScrollView
>
>   - SliverAppBar
>   - SliverToBoxAdapter
>
>     - SingleChildScrollView
>
>       - Column
>       - Container *`// Covered full Scree`*
>       - Button
>           || <-- based on button Click `*//My own code*`
>           Container
>           Child ~> null **OR** `FutureBuilder` `*//My own code*`

This **FutureBuilder** covered under `Container` widget. And I want to get 
size/position of this `Container` widget.

I did it but not proper way.

```
child: FutureBuilder<MealModelData>(
          future: _futureForMealList,
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<MealModelData> snapshot) {

                if (snapshot.data != null) {
                  MealModelData mealMdl = snapshot.data;
                  List<MealList> mealList = mealMdl.mealList;

                  if (mealMdl != null)
                    return ListView.builder(
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: mealList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

                        if (index == mealList.length - 1 && !isGotPos{
                          isGotPos= true;
                          _callBackForGetTopPosition();
                        }

                       .
                       .                       .
                       .                       .
                       .                       .
                       .                       .
                       .                       .
```

And method code is:

```
_callBackForGetTopPosition() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      final RenderBox renderBoxRed =
          _keyForListView.currentContext.findRenderObject();
      final positionRed = renderBoxRed.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
      print('X = ${positionRed.dx} and Y = ${positionRed.dy}')

    });
  }
```

I found this one [How to get a height of a Widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307677/how-to-get-a-height-of-a-widget)

But can't able to declare `SchedulerBinding.instance.....`

Comment: What do you mean by "can't declare scheduler.instance"?

Comment: After googling I can add it by implementing "import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';" Now playing with your answer :) Let me try it by my self

Comment: What do you mean with `when it doesn't render`? Perhaps you want to use Offstage widget.

Comment: It means, Widget not visible initially, It depends upon response of FutureBuilder. Any Idea still i'm not sure about it how can we achieve!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`LayoutBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) to determine the widget's size. Here's a sample to demonstrate how the widget works.

One of the use case of the `LayoutBuilder` widget is determining the dimension of where widgets can be displayed and adapt their size to it.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var dimension = 40.0;

  increaseWidgetSize() {
    setState(() {
      dimension += 20;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Text('Dimension: $dimension'),
          Container(
            color: Colors.teal,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            height: dimension,
            width: dimension,
            // LayoutBuilder inherits its parent widget's dimension. In this case, the Container in teal
            child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
              debugPrint('Max height: ${constraints.maxHeight}, max width: ${constraints.maxWidth}');
              return Container(); // create function here to adapt to the parent widget's constraints
            }),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: increaseWidgetSize,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Demo

[image: demo]

Logs

```
I/flutter (26712): Max height: 40.0, max width: 40.0
I/flutter (26712): Max height: 60.0, max width: 60.0
I/flutter (26712): Max height: 80.0, max width: 80.0
I/flutter (26712): Max height: 100.0, max width: 100.0
```