# Limit amount of characters of Text widget?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to find out how I can limit the amount of characters are show before the ellipsis is shown in a flutter text widget.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

well this does not make sense a little bit to me, I mean if you want to limit amount of your text characters then "ellipsis" does not mean anything at all so just limit your text in a constant length

```
final text = 'hello stack overflow';
Text(text.length > 3 ? '${text.substring(0, 3)}...' : text);
```

Comment: This works for me, I was looking for a way that the widget might have a build in setting to limit the max length.

Comment: instead of '...' import `import 'package:charcode/html_entity.dart';` and use `String.fromCharCode($hellip)`

Answer (score 0):

It is a different problem but I will assume you do not know how to get the size of the text widget, here is how to get that size:  [How to get Widget size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307677/how-to-get-a-height-of-a-widget)

Per how to compute when the text will overflow the bounds take the size of the widget and assign it to widget_width and proceed to use the following pseudo code as follows:

```
double widget_width = computeWidgetWidthAsShownInLinkAbove(context, text_widget);

String    sample = "This text is probably to long to fit";

TextStyle textstyle  = new TextStyle(fontSize: i);

int answer = 0;

for ( int I = 0; I < sample.length ; I = I + 1 ) {
  TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);

  textPainter.text = new TextSpan(
          text: sample.substring(0, I ), style: textstyle);

  textPainter.layout();

  if ( textPainter.width > widget_width ) {
    answer=I-1;  
    break;
  }
}
```