# How to set corner radius based on size on a widget with dynamic size in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, cornerradius

How do I determine the corner radius of a widget using the formula `radius = hight/2` on a button that resizes after its child?

The child in this case is a Text that can be as long as the the passed string is.

This is what I got.
I set the hight and maxWidth to zero in order to wrap the texts size, but I cant figure out a way to measure the width when applying the corner radius.

```
ButtonTheme(
  height: 0,
  minWidth: 0,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(width/2)), //how can i calculate width?
  child: RaisedButton(
    onPressed: onPress,
    child: Text('Some String of variable length'),
  ),
);
```

I've searched the web but nothing comes up.

Comment: I've moved it from the button to collect all variables in the same widget.
It does not make a difference either way.

Comment: see `StadiumBorder` implementation

Comment: Thank you. It does what I need, but not how I wanted it.
Really hoped i could get the size of the child somehow.

Comment: wrap RaisedButton with LayoutBuilder and you will have `constraints` parameter with size

Comment: I did that but the constraint maxWidth and maxHeight showed what I assume to be its parents container. In this case the card it was in.

Comment: so what do you see if you use this: `Container(
 height: 400,
 child: Column(
 children: <Widget>[
 Container(height: 40, color: Colors.red),
 Expanded(child: LayoutBuilder(
 builder: (context, constraints) {
 print(constraints);
 return Container(color: Colors.green);
 }
 )),
 Container(height: 40, color: Colors.blue),
 ],
 ),
 ),` - here you have master parent box with height = 400 and two fixed child boxes (both with height = 40) and one expanded child with unknown height - you know it should be 400 - 40 - 40 = 320 but what do you see in the logs?

Comment: You're right. But it's no the same problem as the code above.
Here you hav no child with unknown hight and width that should determine the size of the parent.
Giving the parent a fixed size and then specify the height of all the children except one is no problem to calculate.
Try copy paste the code above and you'll see that i mean :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @pskink mentioned, you could use [StadiumBorder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/StadiumBorder-class.html):

> A border that fits a stadium-shaped border (a box with semicircles on
>   the ends) within the rectangle of the widget it is applied to.

Here is an example, write multiple lines on the `TextField` to see the result:

```
Center(
  child: Container(
    decoration: ShapeDecoration(
      shape: StadiumBorder(
        side: BorderSide(width: 2.0),
      ),
    ),
    child: TextField(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      minLines: 1,
      maxLines: 100,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: It bothers me that I can't find out the size of the child myself, but this is a perfect solution to my problem.

Comment: Check this to get the size of a widget: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307677/how-to-get-a-height-of-a-widget