# Is there a way to wrap text with a dash in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Is there anyway to automatically wrap text with a dash? (-)

Example:

Not wrapped:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/H1PWj1M]

Wrapped with dash:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/TCm8RFF]

Comment: you can do something programmatically using string length if that's what you're looking for

Comment: @Henok For that I need to get the width of the Card widget and the width of the text widget, how would I do that?

Comment: may be this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307677/how-to-get-a-height-of-a-widget