# Get the Height of a Widget and pass it to expandedHeight

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to place an image as the background of my `AppBar` as in here:

[image]

The only way I know is by using the `flexibleSpace` of a `SliverAppBar` (inside a `CustomScrollView`) as a normal `AppBar` won't change it's size to accommodate the image.

The problem is that a `SliverAppBar` needs a `expandedHeight` that's hardcoded and each of my screens will show a different image that has a different height, so I need to programmatically get the height and pass it to `expandedHeight`.

Is it possible to get the future height of an image, so that the image will not distort and fill the width of the screen, so I can pass it to `expandedHeight`?

Comment: try `image.fit` setting to `Boxfit.cover` for background image or posting `flexibleSpace` code on question might help to answer better

Comment: It doesn't matter, the size is only dependable on `expandedHeight` which receives a double, that's the only thing that changes the height.

Comment: You might need to calculate it, but the only known value in your equation is the width of the screen, from `MediaContext`. Do you know the aspect ratio of the image before having to know its height? If yes then you can calculate what the height will be from screenWidth*aspectRatio

Comment: what if an image have 1000 pixels height, you want to set expandedHeight as 1000 ?

Comment: I don't know the aspect ratio and there won't be 1000 pixels images, they are pictures from photographers, so they are meant to be wide and not tall.