# How to get inside a widget the resulting size of itself shrinked by FittedBox

Tags: flutter

In the code below, a row of two 300x300 boxes (`_Box`) wrapped with `FittedBox` shrinks to fit in the screen. As a result, each box becomes smaller than 300x300.

However, if I get the width of a box in the `build()` method of `_Box` using `RenderBox.size` and `LayoutBuilder()`, the obtained size is `300.0` and `Infinity` respectively.

How can I get the actual displayed size?

I'd like to get it **inside the `_Box` class**, without it getting passed from the parent.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: FittedBox(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                _Box(Colors.red),
                _Box(Colors.orange),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _Box extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Box(this.color);

  final Color color;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
    print(renderBox?.size?.width);  // 300.0

    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (_, constraints) {
        print(constraints.maxWidth);  // Infinity

        return Container(
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
          color: color,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a height of a Widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307677/how-to-get-a-height-of-a-widget)

Comment: @kaboc,please check the below solution and let me know in case of concern

Comment: @KirillMatrosov Agh, I've read the answer several months ago but wasn't aware that it could help this time. Thanks. I'll have a look and see if it really works for my case too.

Comment: @KirillMatrosov With the same approach, I got `300.0` unfortunately.

Comment: Did you find a solution to get the resized size of the widget within a `FittedBox`?

Comment: @leb1755 No, but you reminded me of this question and gave me a chance to look into it again. I wrote a new idea about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72740742/12086560). I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

The Flutter `constraints` object is used to limit how large or small a widget can be rendered, and is usually never really used to get the current size of the widget.

The `renderBox.size` object is of [`Size`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Size-class.html) class, and as a result it has both `renderBox.size.width` and `renderBox.size.height` as defined getters. Note that these values can only be set once the layout phase of the current view is over: see the [`findRenderObject()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/findRenderObject.html) docs page.

This means that you will have to avoid calling `findRenderObject()` from the `build()` method. Instead you will have to define a callback function that must execute after the layout process is complete. You can do this using that have widgets that have callback functions like `onTap` or `onSelected`. How you implement this and finally get the actual layout size by running the callback function is totally dependent on your use case.

Further recommended reading:

1. [DevelopPaper - Sample code for getting the width and height of screen and widget in Flutter](https://developpaper.com/sample-code-for-getting-the-width-and-height-of-screen-and-widget-in-flutter/)
2. [Flutter on Github - How to get a height of a widget? #16061](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16061)
3. [Rémi Rousselet's amazing answer explaining his workaround (using an `Overlay` widget)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307677/how-to-get-a-height-of-a-widget)

Comment: Thanks. I'm conscious about the timing when `renderBox.size.width` is set, which is why I've used `?.` like `renderBox?.size?.width`. I'll read through the linked pages, but can you elaborate how it can actually be achieved? Your answer itself does not give a quick solution for other developers, although I think it contains important information and is helpful even if not the exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question, although it is not a direct answer.

I couldn't find a way to get the size shrinked by `FittedBox`, but I realised that I was able to get around it by using `Flexible` instead.

```dart
SafeArea(
  child: Row(
    children: const [
      Flexible(
        child: _Box(Colors.red),
      ),
      Flexible(
        child: _Box(Colors.orange),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 300.0),
    child: AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1.0,
      child: ColoredBox(color: color),
    ),
  );
}
```

It still seems impossible to get the size via `RenderBox`, and it is now possible with `LayoutBuilder`. But either way, I didn't need them.

The constraints of the two boxies are shrinked by `Flexible` if a smaller space is available, but they expand as big as the space allows, so I limited the maximum size using `ConstrainedBox` and `AspectRatio`.

I didn't have to stick to `FittedBox`. I think I was obsessed with the idea of using it and couldn't think of other solutions when I posted the question two years ago.