# How to use SizeChangedLayoutNotifier?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I got a `Wrap` inside my flexibleSpace in my `SliverAppBar`. Now when the size of my Wrap changes (dynamically) I need to get a notification, so I can change the height of my flexibleSpace in my SliverAppBar accordingly.

I read the docs to the [SizeChangedLayoutNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizeChangedLayoutNotifier-class.html) but I don't really understand how to use it. I wrapped my `Wrap` as a child in a `SizeChangedLayoutNotifier` but for me it is very unclear how to catch the notification with the `NotificationListener<SizeChangedLayoutNotification>`. I couldn't find any code example.

I would really appreciate your help :) Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally figured it out and will post the solution here for others, having the same problem.

I put my `Wrap` inside like this:

```
new NotificationListener<SizeChangedLayoutNotification>(
   onNotification: gotNotification,
   child: SizeChangedLayoutNotifier(
       key: _filterBarChangeKey,
       child: Wrap( // my WRAP stuff)
   )
);
```

and having my callback like this:

```
bool gotNotification(SizeChangedLayoutNotification notification) {
    // change height here
    _filterBarChangeKey = GlobalKey();
}
```

I also found another solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60868972/2813152) not using SizeChangedLayoutNotification at all to solve my problem. For me this was even better. I just wrapped my Widget inside an `MeaserSize` widget which provides an `onSizeChanged` callback.

```
typedef void OnWidgetSizeChange(Size size);

class MeasureSize extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final OnWidgetSizeChange onChange;

  const MeasureSize({
    Key key,
    @required this.onChange,
    @required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MeasureSizeState createState() => _MeasureSizeState();
}

class _MeasureSizeState extends State<MeasureSize> {
  var widgetKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) =>  widget.onChange(widgetKey.currentContext.size));

    return Container(
      key: widgetKey,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: calling `widget.onChange` on build (regardless if you are using `WidgetsBinding.instnace.addPostFrameCallback`) might cause loop if you are going to refresh the same widget with the `widget.onChange` (eg: setState), so I suggest that use combination of both: `addPostFramecallback` on `initState` to get initial height, then use the `NotificationListener` for succeeding changes.