# How can I get the height of a flutter widget?

Tags: flutter

How can I get the height of a flutter widget? I think it's using key, but I don't know how.
For example I want to get the height of a container, which will be in a stack to be able to put the padding of a list view and that at the initial moment it is under the container.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307677/how-to-get-a-height-of-a-widget

Comment: Do you need the height before building the stack? In that case use a LayoutBuilder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a height of a Widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307677/how-to-get-a-height-of-a-widget)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re wanting to get the height before the children widget are built, use a LayoutBuilder widget to wrap the descendants.

Otherwise you can also check the dev tools by using the Select Wifget tool and looking at the widget”s properties