# Flutter: get widget size before build

Tags: flutter, widget, size

Is there any way to measure the dimensions of a widget that hasn't been build, but it's just a variable example:

Column myColumn = Column(children[......]);

myColumn.iWouldLikeToGetItsHeightAndWidth();

Comment: Please take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49650741/12030116), this might help you.

Comment: The simplest solution is to follow the example in the doc of [BuildOwner](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildOwner-class.html). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74701386/7215915). That way you can use `final size = MeasureUtil.measureWidget(myColumn)`

Comment: can you please tell us the actual requirement?

Answer (score 1):

To iterate, the post mentioned in the comment seems to be the solution of what you are looking for. As mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49650741):

> To get the size/position of a widget on screen, you can use GlobalKey
> to get its BuildContext to then find the RenderBox of that specific
> widget, which will contain its global position and rendered size.
>
> Just one thing to be careful of: That context may not exist if the
> widget is not rendered. Which can cause a problem with ListView as
> widgets are rendered only if they are potentially visible.
>
> Another problem is that you can't get a widget's RenderBox during
> build call as the widget hasn't been rendered yet.

To appreciate it better, you can visit the example in [this blog](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-widget-size-and-position-b0a9ffed9407). Take a look from the demo code:

> ```
>    _getSizes() {
>    }
>
>    _getPositions(){
>    }
>
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Scaffold(
>       appBar: AppBar(
>       ),
>       body: Column(
>         children: <Widget>[
>           Flexible(
>             flex: 2,
>             child: Container(
>               color: Colors.red,
>             ),
>           ),
>           Flexible(
>             flex: 1,
>             child: Container(
>               color: Colors.purple,
>             ),
>           ),
>           Flexible(
>             flex: 3,
>             child: Container(
>               color: Colors.green,
>             ),
>           ),
>           Spacer(),
>           Padding(
>             padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
>             child: Row(
>               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
>               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
>               children: <Widget>[
>                 MaterialButton(
>                   elevation: 5.0,
>                   padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
>                   color: Colors.grey,
>                   child: Text("Get Sizes"),
>                   onPressed: _getSizes,
>                 ),
>                 MaterialButton(
>                   elevation: 5.0,
>                   color: Colors.grey,
>                   padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
>                   child: Text("Get Positions"),
>                   onPressed: _getPositions,
>                 )
>               ],
>             ),
>           )
>         ],
>       ),
>     );
>   }
> ```
>
> [image]

In this example, focus on the red panel:

> #### Get the size of a Widget In order to do that, we need our Widget to have a Key, for this we create a GlobalKey and assign it to our
>
> Widget.
>
> ```
> //creating Key for red panel
> GlobalKey _keyRed = GlobalKey();
> ...
> //set key
>     Flexible(
>              flex: 2,
>              child: Container(
>                key: _keyRed,
>                color: Colors.red,
>              ),
>      ),
> ```
>
> Once our Widget already has a Key, we can use this Key to be able to
> obtain the size in the following way:
>
> ```
> _getSizes() {
>     final RenderBox renderBoxRed = _keyRed.currentContext.findRenderObject();
>     final sizeRed = renderBoxRed.size;
>     print("SIZE of Red: $sizeRed");
>  }
> ```
>
> If we press the Get Sizes button, you’ll get this result in the
> console:
>
> ```
> flutter: SIZE of Red: Size(375.0, 152.9)
> ```
>
> now we know that our Red panel has 375.0 as width and 152.9 as height

Comment: I'm getting compile error on this line, `final RenderBox renderBoxRed = _keyRed.currentContext.findRenderObject();`. Can't cast render object to render box

Answer (score 0):

you can use mixin class and  `override afterFirstLayout` and get size from context

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

mixin AfterLayoutMixin<T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.endOfFrame.then(
      (_) {
        if (mounted) afterFirstLayout(context);
      },
    );
  }

  FutureOr<void> afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

class WidgetSize extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Function<Size> onChange;

  const WidgetSize({
    Key? key,
    required this.onChange,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WidgetSize> createState() => _WidgetSizeState();
}

class _WidgetSizeState extends State<WidgetSize> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(postFrameCallback);
    return Container(
      key: widgetKey,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }

  var widgetKey = GlobalKey();
  Size? oldSize;

  void postFrameCallback(_) {
    var context = widgetKey.currentContext;
    if (context == null) return;

    var newSize = context.size;
    if (oldSize == newSize) return;

    oldSize = newSize;
    widget.onChange(newSize);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).