# How do I find the height of a Stack widget tree in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Let's say I have a `Stack` widget and within that I have a bunch of Containers. The last widget of the `Stack` is a `Text` widget and I want to set the text to the height of the `Stack` (until the `Text` widget).

I've tried using a `LayoutBuilder`. So, I wrapped the last `Text` widget with a `LayoutBuilder` and tried to set the height to `constraints.maHeight`, but for some reason it gives me my screen size's height instead.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of a widget using its `GlobalKey` to get its `BuildContext` and use it to find the `RenderBox` which contains the size and position information.

Note that you cannot do this before the build since the widget has not been rendered yet. Similarly, widgets like `ListView` may also cause problems.

A workaround is using `Overlay` widget and its `OverlayEntry` which gives you a `stack-like` widget but it renders after the whole tree renders. Which allows you to get the rendered sizes without a problem. However, there are some details on how to use it. I suggest checking out some use cases from the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html) before getting started.

Comment: Could you share a minimal widget tree example to demonstrate ?  The example on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307677/how-to-get-height-of-a-widget?rq=1)  was too complex for me to understand