# How to find height of widget and set padding of GoogleMap in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, height

I am using [google_maps_flutter: ^1.1.1](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter)

I need to find the `height` of a Widget and set padding according to this `height`.

[image: Here is the picture link]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: [How to get height of a Widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307677/how-to-get-height-of-a-widget)

And also you can use this package,
https://pub.dev/packages/render_metrics
combining with:
https://pub.dev/packages/after_layout.

Second package is for callback after first layout build.