# Can I use the width in a flutter widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm very new to Flutter so please bear with me. I wonder whether I can retrieve and use the width of a widget inside the `build` method.  The RoundButton widget below illustrates two cases where having the width could be useful:

- to display the width as text
- to create a circular Container, I could use `radius=width/2` (Note: I know this can be done using `shape: BoxShape.circle` so it's just an example where having the width could be useful)

So I have two questions:

- is it possible to get the width of the widget
- if so, can you outline how this can be done?

```
class RoundButton extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
        child: Container (
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(width: 6, color: Colors.green),
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(**width**/2)),
              //shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),

            child: Center (
              child: Text(
              "w="+**width**.toString(),
            ),
          )
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get height of a Widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307677/how-to-get-height-of-a-widget)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this can be done without `LayoutBuilder` using the code below.  Note that the two `const` on the `borderRadius` line had to be removed

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    RenderBox rb = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    final Size size = rb?.size ?? Size.zero;
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
        child: Container (
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(width: 6, color: Colors.green),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(size.width.toInt()/2)),
              //shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),

            child: Center (
              child: Text(
              "w="+size.height.toString(),
            ),
          )
        ));
  }
```